# How to cancel an .htaccess rewrite to a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to cancel an .htaccess rewrite that redirects people from mysite.com to mysite.com/blog.

I previously wanted to bypass the main page and send users straight to a subdirectory, so I added a rewrite. Now I want people to be able to access mysite.com, but still be able to reach mysite.com/blog (but only when they follow a link to mysite.com/blog, not by default). I'm a beginner to .htaccess, so I appreciate the patience and help.

Here's what was in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dreamybeast.design$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

I thought that just commenting out my rewrite code in the .htaccess file would stop the site from redirecting mysite.com to mysite.com/blog, but I'm still not able to land on mysite.com at all.

I also tried deleting the .htaccess file (there was nothing else in it) and I still can't land on the root url.

--- edit ---

There's an .htaccess file in the blog subfolder (which contains a Wordpress install) with the following code in it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Is it possible that this is what's causing the redirect, not the .htaccess file in the root?

Comment: Neither new nor old rules , just remove the rules above and website will work as default as you want

Comment: Hi Mohammed, I tried removing the rules, and I tried deleting the .htaccess file. Neither changed anything. The site is still redirecting to the subfolder.

Comment: empty browser cache then test it

Comment: Just tried clearing the cache, no change.

Comment: As you said you previously add them to specific redirection so , website should back to normal when delete them , are there any other rules ? another htaccess?

Comment: I've been searching the folder, but there's no other .htaccess file in the root. Could an .htaccess in a subfolder affect it?

Comment: suppose that you have htaccess in blog subfolder so ,any rules to redirect that folder to another location should work

Comment: I updated the initial post with some code I found in the .htaccess of the subfolder "blog" (which contains a Wordpress install). I did try to remove those lines, but it doesn't seem like it did anything to change the redirect.

Comment: try to change this line RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]  at main root htaccess to RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] and let me know what happen

Comment: also change this line RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dreamybeast.design$  to this  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't appear to change anything either.

Comment: Ok , wait i will try to do something else

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L,NE]

Comment: put rules above in main root htaccess

Comment: Still no change, I'm afraid. I must have messed something up pretty badly!

Comment: no , every problem has a solution , tell me , when you install wordpress , did you was able to explore the website and then press blog to go to blog ? or that happened after installation?

Comment: It's been several years since I installed it. From what I remember, I initially had a basic site at the main site, then I created the blog subfolder in order to contain the Wordpress install. Then once I had the Wordpress install in /blog, I used the .htaccess to redirect the main page to the /blog subdirectory.

Comment: ok , check the index page in main root and see what inside it , maybe you added some code there , header , meta , script etc.

Comment: Looking in the root index.html, the only line I don't recognize is in the head:
    <meta name="p:domain_verify" 
    content="02cc9462c218f7c4bb5b00f6a0360893"/>

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have to go to bed. I'll keep working on it tomorrow. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Mohammed, I figured out my problem! When I thought I was updating my live site, I was actually updating a ghost version of my site that was previously hosted by a different company. I had to retrieve access to my active account to access the files that influence my live site. Thank you so much for your help, my friend. I really appreciate it.

Comment: glad to hear that and you're welcome , thanks